# Understanding Folds in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold, binary-operators, associativity

From what I understand about folds in Haskell, `foldl (-) 0 [1..5]` gives a result of `-15` by calculating `0-1-2-3-4-5`, and `foldr (-) 0 [1..5]` gives a result of `-5` by calculating `5-4-3-2-1-0`. Why is it then that both `foldl (++) "" ["a", "b", "c"]` and `foldr (++) "" ["a", "b", "c"]` give a result of `"abc"`, and the result of `foldr` is not, instead, `"cba"`?

Is there something I'm missing in understanding the differences between `foldl` and `foldr`?

Comment: `foldr (%) d [a,b,c] = a % (b % (c % d))`, whereas `foldl (%) d [a,b,c] = ((a % b) % c) % d`.

Comment: Just read https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think [this part from the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) makes it clearer:

---

> In the case of lists, foldr, when applied to a binary operator, a starting value (typically the right-identity of the operator), and a list, reduces the list using the binary operator, from right to left:
>
> ```
> foldr f z [x1, x2, ..., xn] == x1 `f` (x2 `f` ... (xn `f` z)...)
> ```
>
> . . .
>
> In the case of lists, foldl, when applied to a binary operator, a starting value (typically the left-identity of the operator), and a list, reduces the list using the binary operator, from left to right:
>
> ```
> foldl f z [x1, x2, ..., xn] == (...((z `f` x1) `f` x2) `f`...) `f` xn
> ```

---

If you look at the example breakdown, the concatenation `foldr` is equivalent to:

```
"a" ++ ("b" ++ ("c" ++ ""))
```

And for `foldl`, it would be equivalent to:

```
(("" ++ "a") ++ "b") ++ "c"
```

For string concatenation, these are the same.

---

For subtraction however,

```
1 - (2 - (3 - 0))
```

Gives a different result than:

```
((0 - 1) - 2) - 3
```

Answer (score 8):

Actually `foldr (-) 0 [1..5]` equals `3`, because it's:

```
(1 - (2 - (3 - (4 - (5 - 0))))
```

The answer to this question is in the type of `foldr` function:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

As we see, `(a -> b -> b)` function has iterated element as the first argument and accumulator as the second one. That's why with `foldr (++) "" ["a", "b", "c"]` we have:

```
("a" ++ ("b" ++ ("c" ++ "")))
```

Comment: Very important point about the argument order. They are ordered such that the expanded expression has its arguments in the same order as the list, and the accumulator need not be the same type as the list entries. For instance, `any (>5) xs` can be expressed as `foldr False (\v a -> if v>5 then True else a) xs`.

Answer (score 3):

Seen symbolically as a "translation" of the fold, `0-1-2-3-4-5` by itself is ill-defined. The order of operations *must* be specified.

In fact, whatever the operator, the order is

```
foldl (-) 0 [1..5] = ((((0 - 1) - 2) - 3) - 4) - 5    -- = -15

foldr (-) 0 [1..5] = 1 - (2 - (3 - (4 - (5 - 0))))    -- = 3
```

For the `(++)` though, both orderings result in the same result, when `""` is used in place of `0`.

Comment: `0-1-2-3-4-5` is defined; it's `sum [0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5]`, which means the binary `-` is left associative  (`:i (-)` says `infixl 6 -`). Thus it matches the `foldl` case here.

Comment: of course, there's no question about it. What I meant was that with the `-` seen symbolically, as the stand-in for any possible operator, it is not fully defined without specifying the associativity (as the fixity declaration in Haskell does).

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the most instructive way to get the difference (because the idea of 'left associative' is new to me):
-- comments reflect :doc foldr and :doc foldl

*Main> foldr (-) 2 [1,4,8] -- foldr f z [a,b,c] == a `f` (b `f`(c `f` z))

3

*Main> 1 - (4 - ( 8 - 2) ) -- foldr right associative

3

*Main> ((2 - 1) - 4) -8    -- foldl left associative

-11

*Main> foldl (-) 2 [1,4,8] -- foldl f z [a,b,c] == ((z `f` a) `f` b) `f` c

-11